# 'No storage connection string found.' when trying to list durable function instances from azure functions core tools

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I am currently trying to list all instances of an activity function and the orchestrator function using azure function core tools. The application synchronizes data from different sources into a centralized location.

The setup is as follows:

```
TimerTrigger -> Durable Orchestrator -> Multiple Activity Functions
```

In my concrete example, it is like this:

```
Start Synchronization -> Orchestrate Synchronizations -> Synchronize Source
```

So we start the synchronization process which starts the orchestrator. The orchestrator then starts multiple different synchronizations, one for each source. The problem though is that I cannot seem to get the azure function core tools to list me all instances of the functions I am interested in.

Unfortunately, I would really prefer not to have to use the REST api to query for this information. The setup really complicates things with IP restrictions and managed identity authentication. I think I can correct the setup to get things to work from my network + user, if really needed, but I think that will take way longer than required.

I have tried running the following command:

```
func durable get-instances
```

in a directory with a file called `host.json` with the following contents:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage":"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=Name;AccountKey=Key;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
}
```

I have also tried where the contents of the file are as follows:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
      "durableTask": {
        "storageProvider": {
          "connectionStringName": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=Name;AccountKey=Key;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I have tried calling the `func durable get-instances` with and without the `--connection-string-setting` parameter, with the values `'AzureWebJobsStorage'` and `'extensions:durableTask:storageProvider:connectionStringName'`, but nothing seems to work. I keep getting the error `No storage connection string found.`

I know that the connection string is correct. I have pulled it directly from the storage account 'Access keys' blade.

[image: 'Access keys' blade]

Is there anything I am missing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should specify only the setting name in `connectionStringName`. The setting is locally in local.settings.json and in Azure in the Configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @juunas, I got it to work. I edited the host.json file to have the following content:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0"
}
```

and created another file called local.settings.json with the following contents:

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=Name;AccountKey=Key;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
  }
}
```

Running `func durable get-instances` now works and returns a continuation token, but an empty list. I was not expecting that, but I can now start exploring and understanding here what is going on.

Comment: I highly recommend the [Azure Durable Functions Monitor](https://github.com/microsoft/DurableFunctionsMonitor) for looking at and debugging instances. I installed Azure Functions Core Tools locally and then run the monitor from within Visual Studio Code by right-clicking the host.json.